# Can't Configure CISCO ASA 5505 firewall

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, security

HELP ME..!!!!
I want to Design my Network as like as Below. 
I tried several times but Failed (Failed to ping Web server from my Local LAN and also from LAN).

My configuration is:

```
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.16.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 203.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan3
 no forward interface Vlan 1
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.27.51 255.255.255.248
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 3
!
dhcpd address 192.168.16.5-192.168.16.16 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
object network LAN
 subnet 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0
object network out
 subnet 203.1.1.0 255.255.255.248
!
!
route dmz 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.27.52 1
!
access-list in_to_dmz extended permit tcp any any
access-list in_to_dmz extended permit icmp any any
!
!
access-group in_to_dmz in interface dmz
object network out
 nat (outside,dmz) dynamic interface
access-group in_to_dmz in interface dmz
object network LAN
 nat (inside,dmz) dynamic interface
```

[image]

Comment: You should better describe what you mean by failed.

Comment: Failed to ping Web server from my Local LAN and also from LAN

Comment: @RipanRay What license do you have?

Comment: In my office it's "ASA5505 with Security Plus Software". But I tried this one in Packet Tracer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you ping from the ASA all the other @IP ?

If I understand your design, I think your default route have to be : 
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 203.1.1.1 1

Comment: Yaa. You are right.